# Entity Framework Core 2.0: One-To-Many-Relationship only works once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Angular-Frontend and Entity Framework Core 2.0. I have following DbSets: `DbSet<Vocabulary> Vocabularies` and `DbSet<Word> Words`, while the class `Vocabulary` contains a collection of words: `List<Word> Words { get; set; }`. In my API-Controller I've written a method which provides the vocabularies to the frontend as a response to an HTTP-Get-request. To test my database-connection and everything, I used the same method to create an initial record into my database:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Vocabulary> Get()
{
    if (!Context.Vocabularies.Any())
    {
        Context.Vocabularies.Add(new Vocabulary
        {
            Name = "MyVocabulary",
            Words = new List<Word>
            {
                new Word
                {
                    PrimaryLanguage="Test",
                    SecondaryLanguage="Test",
                    Score= 0
                }
            }
        });
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Context.Vocabularies;
}
```

Now, the weird thing is that when the DB is empty, everything works as expected. When I reload the page (or restart the local IIS) and the HTTP-GET-request happens again, I get all vocabularies with correct ID's etc. but the property `Words` is null... I'm using a local SQL Server database. The tables seem ok, the words have the correct `VocabularyId`.

I just found out that there's a method called `Include()`. Tried it the following way: `return Context.Vocabularies.Include(v => v.Words);`, but didn't work either.

Vocabulary.cs:

```
public class Vocabulary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Word> Words { get; set; }
}
```

Word.cs:

```
public class Word
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryLanguage { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryLanguage { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is helpful to include you model definitions.

Comment: @illug alright, thanks for the advice, added my model classes.

Comment: Try `Context.Vocabularies.Include(v => v.Words).ToList()`

Comment: @IvanMladenov tried it, didn't work unfortunately, still the same problem

Comment: On the original GET, does the db get populated correctly?

Comment: This is bit strange since it actually should work with include and to list. Did you change context maybe and didnt rebuild DB? Try to use before call ensurecreated(). Otherwise try and see if data in database is correct with SQL view in vs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have not fully defined the relationship between the two models. Based on this documentation

[Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

You are missing the link from Word back to Vocabulary. Adding this to the Word class should solve it:

```
public int VocabularyId {get; set; }
```